# Java, Weka: How to predict numeric attribute?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, bayesian

I was trying to use NaiveBayesUpdateable classifier from Weka. My data contains both nominal and numeric attributes:

```
  @relation cars
  @attribute country {FR, UK, ...}
  @attribute city {London, Paris, ...}
  @attribute car_make {Toyota, BMW, ...}
  @attribute price numeric   %% car price 
  @attribute sales numeric   %% number of cars sold
```

I need to predict the number of sales (numeric!) based on other attributes.

I understand that I can not use numeric attribute for Bayes classification in Weka.
One technique is to split value of numeric attribute in N intervals of length k and use instead nominal attribute, where n is a class name, like this: @attribute class {1,2,3,...N}.

Yet numeric attribute that I need to predict ranges from 0 to 1 000 000. Creating 1 000 000 classes make no sense at all.
How to predict numeric attribute with Weka or what algorithms to look for in case Weka has no tools for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a classification problem at all. You should use a [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) model for this, e.g. [`LinearRegression`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/functions/LinearRegression.html).

Comment: In what cases the following technique can be used: Split value of numeric attribute in N intervals of length k and use instead nominal attribute, where n is a class name, like this: @attribute class {1,2,3,...N} ?.

Comment: @AntonAshanin: that's a good idea when handing real-valued *features* to an NB classifier.

Answer (score 0):

As @larsmans mentioned, it's not classification, but rather regression model. The problem is that regression works only with numeric data. Standard approach for categorical data is to use so-called [**dummy variables**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_%28statistics%29). Each dummy variable represents one state of categorical variable and is either 1 or 0. Your attribute list, thus, may be changed to something like this:

```
@relation cars
@attribute country_FR
@attribute country_UK
...
@attribute city_London
@attribute city_Paris
...
```

For example, if city is London, then variable `city_London` will be set to 1 and all other `city_*` vars will be set to 0.

Comment: In what cases the following technique can be used: Split value of numeric attribute in N intervals of length k and use instead nominal attribute, where n is a class name, like this: @attribute class {1,2,3,...N} ?.

Comment: Won't Weka handle this internally?

Comment: Weka uses this conversion internally, but you will not be able to get things like parameter coefficients this way. To have complete control over the attribute set, use `NominalToBinary` filter first.